# MS CRM mail merge

Tags: dynamics-crm, mailmerge

I am using ms crm 2013 web client and office 2013. I started mail merge from marketing list which worked fine, I updated the template, and send me the email. Recipient recevied the email, still Ok. But, there is no activity created in CRM. In 2011 I remember seeing a dialog asking to create actrivity in CRM, I did not see any such dialog and neither the actvities are created in CRM.
Read about it being a bug and fixed in SP1 which I have already.
Please help.

Comment: Why do you think no activity was created, e.g. where did you look for the activity?

Comment: i looked in all possible views. All activities etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you initiate the Mail Merge process (by clicking the Mail Merge button) from the WEB Client (website) it will not pop the window in Word to create activities in CRM.

You need to use the Outlook Client, navigate to Marketing Lists, then start the Mail Merge. This then has a "connection" back to your CRM database, and it will ask you if you want to generate activities after you click Finish & Print.